# Using Cookie for Authentication with Restful service in Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

I've used Spring Security to secure RESTful web services built with Spring, but in the past the request has used authentication headers for the authentication. Now I need to secure an application like that when the user's credentials are in a cookie.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to either extract the user's information from the cookie and put it into an authentication header, or ideally just use the value of the cookie for the `loadUserByUsername` method in the `UserDetailsService` bean.

So far I've come up with a few ideas for how I could do this:

1. I could add a `HandlerInterceptor` to use the cookie to add authentication headers to the requests. However, not all requests require authentication, so if I did this I would want to apply it to certain methods or request mappings and not others, and I don't know how to do that.
2. I could implement an `AuthenticationEntryPoint` as show in [this tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/31/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security-3-1-part-3/). In that tutorial though I really don't understand why he has `response.sendError( HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized" );` as the body of the `commence` method. In my use case, would I be adding an authentication header using the cookie there?
3. I could just perform security checks using a custom method in the first line of all my controller methods. It seems like when you follow Spring Security's ideal path, it's a pretty good solution. What I need to do seems to be straying from that, though, and my requirements are actually quite simple. Maybe I'd be better off just doing this the easy old-fashioned way?
4. Some better idea I don't know about / haven't thought of!

I appreciate your help and thoughts!

Comment: Note: it is not secure to store a user password in cookie. You can solve your problem without store it in the cookie.

Comment: @Michael I appreciate the advice, but there actually isn't a password in the cookie. The fact that I need to use that cookie's value for authentication is outside my control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got your requirements correctly, it might be the easiest to use Spring Security's [Pre-Authentication Framework Classes](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/preauth.html#d0e6156) to implement the desired auth mechanism.

In general, these classes were designed to support scenarios, where the authentication mechanism is provided by some external system which ensures that http requests contain some kind of authentication information that can be used by any webapp. In your case the auth info seems to be in a cookie that can be used to identify the user.

Assuming that you already have a `UserDetailsService` implementation to look up users by their name, you could very easily implement your requirements:

1) Create a subclass of `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` implementing the abstract method `getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest)` to extract the principal (user name) from the cookie. There is another abstract method (`getPreAuthenticatedCredentials()`) that may simply return null, if there are no credentials in the request. The logic already implemented in the abstract superclass then creates an auth token containing the extracted principal, and submits that to the auth manager.

2) Create a bean of type `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` which will receive the auth token from the auth manager, in order to fully populate it (load the user's roles). This class needs to be injected with a variant of the `UserDetailsService` that takes the whole auth token instead of just the user name. You can simply use the `UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper` to adapt your original `UserDetailsService` to that interface:

```
<bean id="preAuthAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
        <bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
            <property name="userDetailsService" ref="yourUserDetailsService"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

3) Wire things together using a configuration similar to what's shown in [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/preauth.html#d0e6156):

```
<security:http>
    ...
    <security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="preAuthFilter" />
</security:http>

<bean id="preAuthFilter" class="com.whatever.YourPreAuthFilter"/>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="preAuthAuthProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

So, all you needed to implement your requirements was a subclass with one single method, and some additional configuration to wire it up with existing supporting classes.

Comment: This is a great response! For now though I'm going to try extending `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and overriding the `attemptAuthentication` method. I'll have it first check for the cookie, and if that isn't present, it'll call the super `attemptAuthentication` method. (There are two different types of authentication that need to happen at different times.) Then I'll just add a custom AuthenticationProvider and the standard UserNameAuth provider implementation. I appreciate your thoughts, though, they have been helpful!

Comment: I did end up using almost this exact solution in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can implement your own cookie filter which extends `GenericFilterBean`

And the config is like below.

```
<security:http ... >
    ....
    <sec:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="cookieAuthenticationFilter" />                                         
</security:http>
```

Have a look at `BasicAuthenticationFilter`. The principle should be very similar.

Note: There is a little difference in `BasicAuthenticationFilter` between different versions. So make sure you find the fit one for reference.